# How can I create a multilanguage multistore?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I want to create two new shops beside my current one. The domain should be the same, but I want to add some suffixes to the domain for the other two stores.
So I want a shop structure like the following:

Multistores:

```
Shop 1: example.com/
Shop 2: example.com/eu/
Shop 3: example.com/us/
```

Multilanguages:

```
Shop 2: example.com/eu/en/
Shop 2: example.com/eu/fr/

Shop 3: example.com/us/en/
Shop 3: example.com/us/fr/
```

For this reason I have created the following structure inside the magento backend:

```
Shop 2 (code: base_eu)          Store EU                German (code: eu_de)
                                                        English (code: eu_en)

Shop 3 (code: base_us)          Store US                German (code: us_de)
                                                        English (code: us_en)
```

Furthermore I have created two subdirectories inside my magento root folder (eu/ and us/) which represents 
the "Shop 2" and "Shop 3" and I have changed the base url of this two shops to example.com/eu/ and example.com/us/.

In Addition I have created a lot of symlinks (app, errors, includes, js, lib, media, skin, var, index.php)
and I have copied the .htaccess inside the subdirectories eu/ and us/.

After this I have modified the htaccess files in both folders:

```
eu/.htaccess -> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE eu_de
us/.htaccess -> SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE us_de
```

So the default store view of both pages is the german store view.

A another solution is to edit the index.php of both directories and add something like this:

```
$mageRunCode = 'base_eu';
$mageRunType = 'website';
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

So I can avoid the htaccess changes, but the result would be the same.

This works great so far, but how can I add the other store views now? Should I add another subdirectories inside the directories for each language or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**

I have tried something like this now:

```
magento_root
    app
    ...
    eu
      (symlinks app, media, ...)
      index.php
      .htaccess
      en
        (symlinks app, media, ...)
        index.php
        .htaccess
```

It's working so far, but this seems to be a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to do this with sub directories you have to create symlinks to your Magento folder:
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/includes/ includes

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/js/ js

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/media/ media

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/skin/ skin

ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var

also copy the index.php to your folders

Comment: Yes, I know that and I have already created the relevant symlinks, but is my directory structure of my question above ok? Because I have to create a lot of symlinks for every store view again and again if a new lanuguage will be added.

Comment: Yes the structure is correct, but I would never add the stores like this. As you can see you have at least 3 stores which are English.

What I would do is buy or develop a module that supports this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have such a module running, which makes websites per country. This way you can adjust the pricing per country/currency and redirect users automatically to the right store. I would suggest this instead of your solution as with time the site will be really slow.

Comment: Ok, thank you then I will take a look at Magento Connect. Can you tell me which extension do you use?

Comment: This is my own extension, don't know if there are any on the connect store.

Comment: Ah ok and is your extension available on github or private?

Comment: It is private, but give me your contact details and I will contact you.